# What does jQuery's $. refer to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, dom

I've seen $. used but I've never understood what it stands for. Example that got me thinking:

```
$.getJSON("url", function(result){
                    $.each(result, function(i, field){
                        $(".test").append(field + " ");
                    });
```

EDIT: Right, I'm embarrassed. I knew it referred to jQuery but I've only used jQuery for DOM manipulation, I'm so used to having elements to be worked on, it threw off guard a little. Thanks for your informative replies.

Comment: take a look jquery code, it is open

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$ is an alias for jQuery - see the very top of the library for the code.

Answer (score 7):

The easy case - `$` and `jQuery` are the same thing assigned to different variables.

`$` is the main `jQuery` object, which is actually a function that you can call, hence the ability to do

```
$(selector)
```

However, functions in JavaScript are objects themselves, so you can attach methods to them and call them later. So `$.each` is actually a method on the `$` object.

Basically `$.` is not something special about jQuery, but simple method invocation.

Answer (score 5):

It's an alias for the jQuery object itself, so instead of having to write:

```
jQuery.getJSON("url", function(result){
                    jQuery.each(result, function(i, field){
                        jQuery(".test").append(field + " ");
                    });
```

you can write the more convenient code (as you have posted)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [JQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#General):

> By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"

It's same as your full name is 'Meghananth Rahtod' and people call you Megh.

Answer (score 2):

It's an alias for jQuery. The $ is a function of jQuery, but when you use `$("")`, `$(null`), `$(undefined)` or `$(false)`, the jQuery return "this", making the call to itself. In the line 100 of jQuery file (development, version 1.8.3) you can see this.

Other ways to call the jQuery: `window.jQuery`, `window.$` or `jQuery`.

You can see more here too: http://www.hackification.com/2008/11/27/a-developers-introduction-to-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Just an alias to the `jQuery` object. Both `$` and `jQuery` do the same.

This is a part of jQuery source code:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

You can access to this here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js
jQuery is **open-source**.

Answer (score 1):

It might be confusing, but `$` is a valid identifier in Javascript.